# jupyter notebook under pyenv in systemd only gives system python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, systemd

I have Jupyter notebook installed under pyenv alias jupyter. if I run it from console (no pyenv activate jupyter, notebooks uses same port):

```
$ export PATH=/home/mortenb/.pyenv/versions/jupyter/bin:$PATH
$ /home/mortenb/.pyenv/versions/jupyter/bin/jupyter-notebook \
  --config=/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

!python --version
Python 3.6.5

!jupyter --paths
config:
    /home/mortenb/.jupyter
    /home/mortenb/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/envs/jupyter/etc/jupyter
    /usr/local/etc/jupyter
    /etc/jupyter
data:
    /home/mortenb/.local/share/jupyter
    /home/mortenb/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/envs/jupyter/share/jupyter
    /usr/local/share/jupyter
    /usr/share/jupyter
runtime:
    /run/user/1000/jupyter
```

Correct kernel all is fine.

But if I automate this with a systemd script, same user, same executable:

```
# cat /lib/systemd/system/jupyter_notebook.service 
[Unit]
Description=jupyter notebook as a service

[Service]
PATH=/home/mortenb/.pyenv/versions/jupyter/bin:$PATH
Type=simple
User=mortenb
Group=mortenb
PIDFile=/var/run/jupyter_notebook.pid
ExecStart=/home/mortenb/.pyenv/versions/jupyter/bin/jupyter-notebook --config=/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I get python 2.7.12 (system python with Ubuntu 16.04)

```
!python --version
Python 2.7.12

!jupyter --paths
config:
    /home/mortenb/.jupyter
    /usr/etc/jupyter
    /usr/local/etc/jupyter
    /etc/jupyter
data:
    /home/mortenb/.local/share/jupyter
    /usr/local/share/jupyter
    /usr/share/jupyter
runtime:
    /home/mortenb/.local/share/jupyter/runtime
```

The jupyter-notebook has the following shebang in both examples:

```
#!/home/mortenb/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/envs/jupyter/bin/python
```

Any idea why systemd startup differs.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> <...>
>
> [Service]
> PATH=/home/mortenb/.pyenv/versions/jupyter/bin:$PATH
> Type=simple
> User=mortenb
> Group=mortenb
> PIDFile=/var/run/jupyter_notebook.pid
> ExecStart=/home/mortenb/.pyenv/versions/jupyter/bin/jupyter-notebook --config=/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
>
> <...>
> ```

Your unit file is syntactically incorrect.

There is no `PATH=` directive (ref. [`systemd.directives`(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.directives.html)) in systemd unit files. You have to use the `Environment=` directive to specify environment variables.

> And systemd does not seem to support expansion.

Actually, systemd *does* support environment variable expansion in `Environment=` and several other directives. However, you have to use `${FOO}` as part of a word; `$FOO` is only recognized as a word of its own. Ref. [`systemd.service`(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines):

> Basic environment variable substitution is supported. Use "${FOO}" as part of a word, or as a word of its own, on the command line, in which case it will be replaced by the value of the environment variable including all whitespace it contains, resulting in a single argument. Use "$FOO" as a separate word on the command line, in which case it will be replaced by the value of the environment variable split at whitespace, resulting in zero or more arguments. For this type of expansion, quotes are respected when splitting into words, and afterwards removed.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the path, setting the path identical to what it was when running in shell solved it. And systemd does not seem to support expansion.

Replacing the path line in jupyter_notebook.service solved my issue:

```
Environment='PATH=/home/mortenb/.pyenv/versions/jupyter/bin:/home/mortenb/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims:/home/mortenb/.pyenv/shims:/home/mortenb/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
```